# A Prolog code to generate prime numbers from 1 to N

Tags: prolog, primes

I've been trying to do a Prolog problem to generate the prime numbers from 1 to N but it keeps  replying with true or false and i cannot find the error.
Query example: generatePrime(10, X)

```
isPrime( 2 ) .
isPrime( P ) :-
  P > 2 ,
  isDivisible( P , P-1 ) .

isDivisible( P , X ) :-
  X > 1,
  P mod X =\= 0 ,
  isDivisible( P , X-1 ) .
isDivisible( _ , X ) :-
  1 is X .

generatePrime( N , X ) :-
  not( isPrime( N ) ) ,
  Z is N-1 ,
  generatePrime( Z , X ) .
generatePrime(N, X):-
  isPrime( N ) ,
  X is N ,
  Z is N-1 ,
  generatePrime( Z , X ) .
generatePrime( 1 , X ) :-
  X is 1 .
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the query your tried and the result you got?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic the query is generatePrime(10, X).

Comment: Note that 1 is not a prime number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to build a list:

```
generatePrime( 1 , [] ) :- !.
generatePrime( N , X ) :-
  not( isPrime( N ) ) , !,
  Z is N-1 ,
  generatePrime( Z , X ) .
generatePrime(N, [N | X] ):-
  Z is N-1 ,
  generatePrime( Z , X ) .
```

I did not test it but something like this should work.

Comment: This is working just fine, thanks a lost. However i wanted the output to be like this
X = 7
X = 5
X = 3
X = 2